# Creating a string list of values in a datatable

Tags: vb.net, string, for-loop, iteration, concatenation

I'm trying to create a list of rates in a program where the rates are running out a month from today, so that a reminder can be sent to the user to extend them. My code for doing so is below

```
Try
    Dim rDt As New DataTable
    Dim r1Dt As New DataTable

    Using rDa = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT [Comm_Code] FROM [Acquisition Commission] WHERE DateTo=?", con)
        rDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today.AddMonths(1)
        rDa.Fill(r1Dt)
    End Using

    Dim r2Dt As New DataTable
    Using r2Da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT [Comm_Code] FROM [Commission Rates] WHERE DateTo=?", con)
        r2Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today.AddMonths(1)
        r2Da.Fill(r2Dt)
    End Using

    Dim r3Dt As New DataTable
    Using r3Da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT [Comm_Code] FROM [Customer Special Rates] WHERE DateTo=?", con)
         r3Da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today.AddMonths(1)
         r3Da.Fill(r3Dt)
    End Using

    rDt = r1Dt.Copy
    rDt.Merge(r2Dt)
    rDt.AcceptChanges()
    rDt.Merge(r3Dt)
    rDt.AcceptChanges()

    If rDt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim rates As String = ""
        For Each dr As DataRow In rDt.Rows
            rates = dr.Item("Comm_Code") & ", "
        Next
        If MsgBox("The following rates; " & rates & "are set to expire in 1 month. Would you like to automatically extend these rates by 6 months?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Extend Rates") = MsgBoxResult.No Then

        Else
```

However, when stepping through this code, I can see that `rDt` has 3 rows (As I expected, 1 rate from each table as a test), but the `For Each` loop only iterates once, so only 1 of the 3 items is concatenated onto the string.

Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override `rates` each time.

`rates = dr.Item("Comm_Code") & ", "`

You need to change it to

`rates &= dr.Item("Comm_Code") & ", "`

Be wary of the extra comma.